# Solr result relevancy with query filter boost

Tags: search, solr, solr-boost

We have implemented Site search for our project. Nutch is used for crawling the content of the site.
Currently, we have all the records being crawled and indexed in SOLR and the search functionality works for any keyword search.
Issue we are facing is the search result relevancy, we are not able to perform boost on fields and show the result.

For example, we are indexing the fields title, description, keywords, URL and content.
When I search for any keyword “XYZ”, all the records with this keyword are displayed based on the term frequency.
However, when I give boost to the field title in query filter-
a.  Title^5 – search results are displayed which has the keyword in title, but it is not picking the records with “XYZ” in content.
b.  Title^5 content^1.1 – in this scenario, search results are not displayed based on the title relevancy, and the default term frequency behavior is noted.

Comment: what score do you see when you enable `debugQuery`?

Comment: I am seeing Score as 0 always

Comment: Please post your query.

Comment: http://localhost:8983/solr/master_SiteSearch_SolrSiteSearch_1/query2?q=Orlando&wt=json&indent=true&defType=edismax&qf=title^20+content^2

http://localhost:8983/solr/master_SiteSearch_SolrSiteSearch_1/query2?q=Orlando&wt=json&indent=true&defType=edismax&qf=title^20